# How to handle external POST request to any page in Adobe CQ 5.5

Tags: aem

What do we need : How to execute a external POST request on any page?

Why do we need : We are developing a secured intranet portal using Adobe CQ for our client. Any request for any page of Adobe CQ of intranet portal redirects to client's interface. This is an external system which generates a TOKEN and sends this token to CQ as an request parameter via HTTP request with POST method.

We set our cookies based on this token which needs to be part of every page. ( We are using page component inhertiance and setting them on root level)

Need suggestions on how this can be achieved. Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: You can expose a servlet on POST method. Once external system comes back to your system, they will hit your servlet. Handle any of your functionality in servlet or redirect to some page from here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are aware about this method. Unfortunately we do not have control over changing the HTTP request POST method URL expression which is set to /content/myProject/*. What we will need is if any GET request is hit on /content/myProject/* it should serve the page. And if any POST request is hit on /content/myProject/* it should be served by the servlet. Also is it recommended to have servlet path for the POST request with /content/* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can defined what method your servlet accepts, so the GET can be handled with a JSP and the POST with a `SlingAllMethodsServlet`.

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@SlingServlet(resourceTypes = "cq:Page", methods = "POST", generateComponent = false)
public class MyPOSTServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

This should get triggered for all pages.

Regarding your comment below your question, never have a servlet path with `/content`. Either a fixed virtual path like `/bin/myservlet` or a `resourceType`.
Check the documentation from Sling: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html

Comment: Thanks @Thomas We are in a shared environment. So we will not be able to register a servlet on resourceTypes. Also we have to run this code on the live copy.

Comment: @yashahuja Live copy shouldn't be an issue these are pages as well, but I see the problem with a shared environment. Are there any indications to identify this specific POST? You could write a Filter instead: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html